# modifying a react element field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Is it possible to have something like:

```
var e = <TableHeaderColumn key={"060"} dataField={'username'} width={'180'} dataSort headerAlign='left'  editable={JSON.parse('{"type": "textarea" }')}>{'Username'}</TableHeaderColumn>];
```

and later change, for example  **width**  using something like:

```
e.width = '45';
```

Comment: Just use it as prop/state and then when you'll change it, it will automatically work

Comment: so, can I do   console.log(e.props.witdh) ?     
also, could I do:    e.props.width = 45?

Comment: No, that's not how it works. React is about describing your UI *declaratively* not imperatively. You would simple rerender the component with the new value for `width`. Since you are not providing a complete example it's difficult to help. Maybe have a look at https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: I was interested on changing the width value. It worked 
console.log('>> e = ' + e.props.width)  
but not for the assignment as I got the error:  Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'width' of object '#<Object>'  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

lets say you have a component that renders a table. and when you click something you want to change the width to be something else. (your question doesn't give any context so I'm making one up)

```
<button onClick={this.handleClick}>Some text</button>
```

and then your handler function looks something like

```
handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({width: '45'});
}
```

when you render your TableHeaderColumn just do this

```
<TableHeaderColumn width={this.state.width}
```

This is a very simple example and may not answer everything, but hopefully you can get an idea of how to use state to change a value on a user action

Comment: thanks... This is the basic way. The problem is that my number of columns is unknown. So, I might have to create a map of with properties.

Comment: why are you trying to specify exact widths for a table row?

Comment: To overcome a problem with the table. There are situations where the width of the columns is too wide for some columns. Each column is a react  component. So, I was wondering on how to correct this problem on my own without touching the table code which I did not create

Comment: if its a table that wouldn't happen. you can also truncate text if its getting too big for the column. it sounds like you are trying to fix an issue the wrong way. can you post an example where its messed up so I can help? you might just need to use css to fix the width issue

Comment: some columns with few text get like 3 times wider than others. The whole table is a React comp. So, this is the problem

Comment: again I'd need to see an example to help you. flying blind here so I can only make guesses :/